# blackberry:position of field in the screen

Tags: blackberry, field

I want to open popup a  screen in the same position of label. So I want a method that return the position of the field in the screen. And then I use these position for the popup.

```
  public void sublayout(int width, int height){
            super.sublayout(width,height);
            setPosition(x_postion_of_label,y_postion_of_labe);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int xPos=labelField.getLeft() ;
```

&

```
int yPos=labelField.getTop();
```

will give you the starting X and Y positions of labelField .